iOS IPA resign issue - Asset validation failed (90179)
While resigning IPA and upload to app store on top of previous version. I see below issue.
Asset validation failed (90179)
The executable 'Payload/MyApp/Frameworks/MaterialComponents.framework/MaterialComponents' must be signed with the certificate that is contained in the provisioning profile. (ID: b502a89e-2303-4bb1-83d6-0498cf132763)
I'm using below command to resign IPA
fastlane sigh resign --signing_identity "Apple Distribution: company name"  --provisioning_profile "myapp.mobileprovision" "myapp.ipa"
Any help appreciated

You should re-sign the files in the Framework, or delete it
